# Can the TestCluster be used to obtain items from the service collection?

Tags: orleans

I've been successfully using the TestCluster to get grain instances for testing. The cluster was configured with several services in its service collection. The service interfaces are injected into the grain classes. There is a `ServiceProvider` property on the test cluster instance and it has a `GetService` method so I thought that I could obtain these services this way from test case code. When I try, I get null for whatever service I ask for. No problem getting grain instances so I know at least that part of it working. I'm sure the services are present because the related tests that rely on the services are passing.

Is it even possible to retrieve the services this way? It doesn't seem like the `ServiceProvider` would even be there if there wasn't some intention that it can be used this way.

**See also**
Repost of question on Orleans repo Q&A
[Can the TestCluster be used to obtain items from the service collection?](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/discussions/8732)

Comment: The TestCluster is primarily used for testing of Orleans grains and silos. It allows you to set up a local test cluster for testing your Orleans application in a controlled environment. While it provides a convenient way to interact with the Orleans runtime during testing, it doesn't directly expose the underlying service collection. To retrieve the service, perhaps you could use dependency injection in your grains and then injecting those dependencies during your tests. So, can you create a minimal, complete sample to reproduce the problem, then we can according to your scenario to research.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting up the `ClusterFixture` on your own, you can make your your services easily available by implementing the `ISiloConfigurator` interface. From the official docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/implementation/testing

```
public class ClusterFixture : IDisposable
{
    public ClusterFixture()
    {
        var builder = new TestClusterBuilder();
        builder.AddSiloBuilderConfigurator<TestSiloConfigurations>();
        Cluster = builder.Build();
        Cluster.Deploy();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cluster.StopAllSilos();
    }

    public TestCluster Cluster { get; }
}

public class TestSiloConfigurations : ISiloConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(ISiloBuilder siloBuilder)
    {
        siloBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<T, Impl>(/* ... */);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: We're using this exact type of setup. The only issue I've been trying to work out is how to get at those services from the unit test code. When I try with `cluster.ServiceProvider.GetService` I only a null back.

Comment: You're right, I was able to check it out and found out that you have to add the `public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }` property to `ClusterFixture`, and then create a Host for your services: 
```var host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<ISampleService, SampleService>();
            }).Build();
```
and then simply initialize the ServiceProvider: `ServiceProvider = host.Services;` I'm not sure why